# How to prove $\sum \sqrt{\frac{a^2+2bc}{b+c}} \geq \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{a+b+c}$ for all $a,b,c \ge 0$?

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative real numbers such that $ab+bc+ca>0$, prove that
$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2+2bc}{b+c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b^2+2ca}{c+a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c^2+2ab}{a+b}} \ge \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}\sqrt{a+b+c}$$

I found it [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h225653p1252690) and also [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1274101p6672547). But there are no simple nice solutions at all, and I don't know how they can find the Holder's yields. Here's my motivation
I try to use Cauchy Schwarz
$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \sqrt{\frac{a^2+2bc}{b+c}}\right)^2 \cdot \sum_{cyc} (b+c)(2a^2+bc)^2 \ge (a+b+c)^6$$
but the equality cases $a=b=c$ or $(0,t,t)$ aren't ensured. So far, I haven't had any more ideas. Can someone help me with this problem? And tell me why people can find the Holder's yields. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Some thoughts.**

It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \sqrt{\frac{a^2 + 2bc}{b + c}\cdot \frac{2}{a + b + c}} \ge 3.$$

**Fact 1.** Let $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2 + \frac{33}{16}x^2y^2z^2 \ge \frac{81}{16}$. Then $x + y + z \ge 3$.
(*Note*: It is verified by *Mathematica*. A human verifiable proof is needed.)

Now, let
$$x := \sqrt{\frac{a^2 + 2bc}{b + c}\cdot \frac{2}{a + b + c}}, \quad \mathrm{etc.}$$

We have
$$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2 + \frac{33}{16}x^2y^2z^2 \ge \frac{81}{16}.$$
(This can be proved by the Buffalo Way (BW).)

By Fact 1, we have $x + y + z \ge 3$.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting and powerful lemma! The rest is not hard, and I could solve it by myself. Thank you, River Li

Comment: @30AnhTi711 I want to see a nice proof, although I can not find a nice proof.

Comment: The inequality is strong, I think. Hope someone will have nice proof for it. I also find this https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u1051050h3231885p29609849

Comment: For this lemma and in case the OP, we can choose the range $33/16 M\le 5/2$ specificlly.

Comment: @Helloworld Really? I am not sure.

Comment: For $5/2$ is is less calculates

Comment: @Helloworld Right. I see.

Comment: @RiverLi Could you please help me prove this problem? 
$$27(a^4+b^4+c^4+d^4)+148abcd\ge (a+b+c+d)^4, \forall a,b,c,d\ge 0.$$

Comment: @Helloworld BW works. Also, let $d=1$ and try pqr.

Comment: @RiverLi How can we let $d=1$ ?

Comment: @Helloworld The inequality is homogeneous. Or, you divide both sides by $d^4$.

Comment: @RiverLi Wow, it is nice. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From River Li's idea and the help of Khuong Trang, I can solve my problem. Choose $a+b+c=2$.
Now we just need to prove
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{(a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)}{(c+a)(c+b)} + \frac{5(a^2+2bc)(b^2+2ca)(c^2+2ab)}{2(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} \ge \frac{11}{2}$$
or after full expanding and $pqr$, we need to prove
$$f(r)=135r^2+r(171-162q)+10q(q-1)^2 \ge 0$$
we have
$$f'(r)=270r+171-162q$$

If $4/3 >q>23/26$, using Schur
$$f(r) \ge 270\cdot \frac{8(q-1)}{9} +171-162q=3(26q-23) \ge 0$$

If $q \le 23/26$, then $270r+171-162q >270r+171-162\cdot \dfrac{23}{26}>0$ then $f(r)$ increase. Using Schur
$$f(r) \ge f\left(\frac{8(q-1)}{9}\right)=10(q-1)(q-17/5)(q-4/3)\ge 0$$
always true for $4/3>q>1$.
The last case $q<1$ easy to check
$$135r^2+r(171-162q)+10q(q-1)^2 \ge 0$$
Hence, the proof is done.

Comment: Can I ask you, how did you get rid of radicals and get the very first inequality? The rest looks clear.

Comment: @Aig, I get it from River Li. I have no idea how to find it. It seems magical to cancel the radical.

Comment: @RiverLi Please help, where does the initial inequality in this answer come from?

Comment: @Aig I didn't see your comment. Just like pqr, we seek some relations between $x^2, y^2, z^2$ which implies the desired inequality.

Comment: @RiverLi Does isolated fudging help in this case?

Comment: @Helloworld I didn't try.

Comment: @RiverLi Liu Quan Bao tried without success.

Comment: @Helloworld Perhaps it is difficult to find the appropriate form.

Comment: @RiverLi Have you visit this problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4874800/prove-frac1-sqrtab2-frac1-sqrtbc2-frac1-sqrtca2-ge
I think it is very nice and hard.

Comment: @Helloworld I don't have a nice proof.