# Prove: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+a^2}} \geq \frac{2\sqrt{3}+9}{6}$ for $ab+bc+ca=2$

Tags: inequality

> **Problem:** Let $a,b,c$ are non-negatives such that $ab+bc+ca=2$. Prove:
> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+a^2}} \geq \frac{2\sqrt{3}+9}{6}$$

Equality holds iff $(a,b,c) =(2,1,0)$

Currently, I haven't had any ideas for this problem.

I'll really appreciate if you share me some ideas for this problem even if it's not nice.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you get this problem? Very interesting! (already upvoted 3 hours ago)

Comment: @Helloworld I found it.

Comment: What is your original idea?

Comment: @Helloworld I found it by grapher

Comment: How can you check it true? Try all values?

Comment: You can reduce the problem to considering all extremum points.  And you can do that by reducting to a system of equations. We use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier to achieve that goal ; finding the extremum values by getting the system of equations and then solving them. 
Ofcourse that is a calculus approach mainly and perhaps not the method you seek.
Also, it still requires quite alot of work. 

Maybe some kind of averaging inequality works here.

Maybe simplify by writing $c = (2 - ab)/(a+b)$ might help alot. Notice this also implies $2 -ab >= 0$ , what seems useful.

Comment: Another way is using continued fractions but that also requires quite some work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Some thoughts.**

WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a, b, c)$.

By AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+b^2}}
= \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{(a + b^2) \cdot 3}} \ge \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{a + b^2 + 3},$$
and
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{b+c^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+a^2}}
 &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}
  + \frac{8}{2\sqrt{(b+c^2)(c+a^2)\cdot 4}}}\\
 &\ge \sqrt{\frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}
  + \frac{8}{(b+c^2)(c+a^2) + 4}}.
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{a + b^2 + 3} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}
 + \frac{8}{(b+c^2)(c+a^2) + 4}}
\ge \frac{2\sqrt{3}+9}{6}. \tag{1}$$

Let
$$Q := \frac{1}{b+c^2}+\frac{1}{c+a^2}
+ \frac{8}{(b+c^2)(c+a^2) + 4}.$$
By AM-GM, we have
$$\sqrt{Q} = \frac32 \sqrt{\frac49 Q}
= \frac32 \cdot \frac{2\cdot \frac49 Q}{2\sqrt{\frac49 Q \cdot 1}}
\ge \frac32 \cdot \frac{2 \cdot \frac49 Q}{\frac49 Q + 1}. \tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{a + b^2 + 3} + \frac32 \cdot \frac{2 \cdot \frac49 Q}{\frac49 Q + 1}
\ge \frac{2\sqrt{3}+9}{6}. \tag{3}$$
(3) is true which is verified by *Mathematica* (a Computer Algebra System). A human verifiable step-by-step proof is required.

Comment: @DanhTrung It is not nice.

Comment: I think it's the best solution for this problem